# Merge and When Matched query giving an error sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement

I have a query which I am trying to test. The query should update the data if it finds data in the table with existing primary key. If it doesn't then insert into the table.

The Primary key is of type int and in the properties I can see Identity is set to "True" which I assume it means that it will automatically set the new id for the primary if it is inserted.

```
MERGE INTO Test_table t
USING (SELECT 461232 ID,'Test1-data' Fascia FROM Test_table) s
ON (t.ID = s.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET t.Fascia = s.Fascia 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Fascia)
VALUES (s.Fascia);
```

The issue here is this query doesn't work and it never inserts the data or updates. Also, query gets compiled and I don't get any compilation error

Also the reason I want this query is to work because then I will use Java prepared statement to query the database so I am assuming I can do

```
SELECT ? ID,? Fascia FROM Test_table
```

So that I can pass the values with set methods in java.

Please let me know if there is something wrong in my query.

Comment: "The issue here is this query doesn't work". Hang on while I fetch my crystal ball to fathom what's wrong. "query giving an error" Well, what's the error then, why leave us in the dark if you want our help???

Comment: @HoneyBadger I am not leaving you in dark...the query doesn't updates or inserts but it gets executed without any error. updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting from the target table as your source.

You either need to remove your `FROM Test_table` or have at least 1 row in `Test_table` prior to your `merge`.

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XROJD28508

```
MERGE INTO Test_table t
USING (SELECT 461232 ID,'Test1-data' Fascia --FROM Test_table
      ) s
ON (t.ID = s.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET t.Fascia = s.Fascia 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Fascia)
VALUES (s.Fascia);
```

Comment: @SqlZim I am facing same issue can you please explain more what is wrong with FROM ??

Comment: @v8-E The original question was using an empty table with dummy values instead of just using values. If you select from a table with 0 rows, you're going to get 0 rows, even if you're using dummy values in the `select`.